# Cat having chronic tremors

Tags: cats, health, sleep

My cat has been having tremors since he was a kitten. He is currently 14 years old, so apparently, he is able to survive this situation. However, I still would like to improve his condition any way I can.

These tremors have always been coming and going. Generally, twice or three times a year, which lasts anound a month. Then they would just disappear. I was unable to find a seasonality but it seems to be correlating with colder weather (still, I also see the tremors in warm summer days).

Generally, I see the tremors when he is about to go to sleep. While sleeping, he does not have tremors. Sometimes, the tremors appear when he is wide awake and active as well. I think this has something to do with the status of the condition that is the underlying reason. When it is bad, tremors appear when he is active, when it is milder, tremors only appear when transitioning into sleep.

Another pattern that I noticed is that Odin loses weight very quickly when the intensity of the tremors increases.

Over the years, we have tried a lot of things.
He had regular blood checks. Often, he has high urea in the blood. But we have also seen perfectly normal blood values in a period that he has the tremors.
Many years ago, he had an MRI but the doctor said there is nothing to be worried about in the results.
Twice, we checked the cerebrospinal fluid (brain-spinal-fluid). In the result report, it said there were traces of inflammation but the culture did not grow, which the doctor said might be unrelated to the tremors. Still, we applied a long-term antibiotics treatment which yielded no observable improvement.

When he was 5 years old, we decided not to pursue this condition anymore because he was clearly able to survive and not seemingly having any pain during the tremors.

I would like to ask if any of you had a similar experience. Please take a look at the video using the following link. I think the way how these tremors manifest is very peculiar that might indicate a certain condition.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwmjmz3edex328u/2021_odin_tremors.mp4?dl=0

Thank you very much.